# ActiveRecord query by computed value based on each row's values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-geocoder, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to solve a "Find Nearby Deliveries" kind of problem, where you need to find all delivery restaurants whose delivery radius covers your apartment.

Let's say we have

```
# Restaurant.rb
geocoded_by :location
:latitude
:longitude
:radius
```

and I receive a search query

```
# search_queries
search_queries[latitude] = 36.13422
search_queries[longitude] = -122.23411
```

My current inefficient solution using Geocoder is

```
coord = [search_params[:latitude], search_params[:longitude]]
nearby_deliveries = Restaurant.all.select { |res| res.distance_from(coord) <= res.radius }
```

Geocoder provides only a way to search for nearby objects within a radius, but how do I search for objects whose radii cover my target?

I'm thinking that I should do something like (pseudocode)

```
Restaurant.where("radius >= THIS.distance_from(target_lat, target_lng)")
```

or

```
Restaurant.where("radius >= Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([latitude, longitude], [target_lat, target_lng])
```

But I have no idea how I would intertwine Geocoder's calculation into a query.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm won't answer directly but I have two suggestions of ways to solve your problem
of finding nearest neighbors

Look at the gem kdtree https://github.com/gurgeous/kdtree/blob/master/README.md

Or

Look at the service Algolia.com, they offer geolocated search as a feature.